Complex manifold structure on moduli space of holomorphic bundles on Riemann surface
Consider the space $\mathcal N$ of rank $r$, degree $d$ holomorphic bundles on a compact Riemann surface $X$ of genus $g\geq 2$.
Neitzke constructs this by considering $L^2_k$-completions and taking the space to be a quotient of a Banach manifold by a Banach Lie group. The result is (a) a finite dimensional complex manifold and (b), as a topological space, equivalent to the space of slope stable holomorphic bundles quotiented by the automorphism group of the underlying smooth bundle.
Another way of obtaining a moduli space is by taking the GIT quotient of an appropriate Quot scheme by a linearised action (e.g. Hoskins). The complex points of this naturally have a complex manifold structure with similarly pleasant properties as the above.
However, given that we know (a) and (b), there should be a more direct way of describing the complex manifold structure. In particular, I would like to do so without involving infinite dimensional manifolds or schemes.
